# Перемещение элемента jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть такая разметка нескольких блоков с классом `input-box`:

```html
<div class="input-box">
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email">
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control" aria-required="true" placeholder="Email">
  </span>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно с помощью jQuery переместить блок с классом `.line` в `span` с классом `.wpcf7-form-control-wrap`.

Пробую сделать так, но не получается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

```js
$('.input-box').find('.line').prependTo($(this).parent('.input-box').next('.wpcf7-form-control-wrap'));
```

Comment: Добавьте CSS...

Comment: Что вообще должно получится

Comment: Почему в div ничего нет

Comment: Вероятно, должно быть что-то вроде `$('.input-box').find('.line').prependTo($('.input-box').find('.wpcf7-form-control-wrap'));`

Comment: Вам нужно переместить блок при каком то событии? При клике например. Просто первое что хочется сказать возьмите и в html разметке переместите :)

Comment: Автор пользуется плагином для WordPress вроде как, хотя в плагине вроде есть возможность поменять структуру формы.